# What happens when the user swipes an Android App from the Recent Apps List?

Tags: android

If the user swipes my application from the recent apps list, what happens, exactly? Will the application's top window receive a "close" message, or will the application's process receive the `SIGTERM` (or even `SIGKILL`) UNIX signal, or does something else entirely happen?

Also, does the application get a chance to handle and to exit gracefully?

Comment: take a look here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19987/what-actually-happens-when-you-swipe-an-app-out-of-the-recent-apps-list

Comment: @MarcinKrupa They do not give technical details of what happens, however, they explain it from the user's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is the same thing as hitting back several times until the app closes. Here is an interesting (but kinda old) discussion about it.

[Discussion About Swipe killing apps](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/mpevh/id_like_to_squash_this_growing_misconception/c32s7wv)